# What pytest-allure-adaptor version is needed to run with pytest version 5.1.2 which apparently is the latest version

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, allure

I have been struggling to fix this issue. I have pytest version 5.1.2 which is the latest version now. I have tried different versions of pytest-allure-adaptor like 1.4.0 so as to generate allure reports but none of the versions are compatible and I get this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'mangle_testnames' from '_pytest.junitxml'

Can somebody guide me the correct version combination of pytest and pytest-allure-adaptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allure PyTest integration was renamed to `allure-pytest`. https://pypi.org/project/allure-pytest/ . Source code was moved to new repository https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python

Please consider migration to `allure-pytest` in order to support latest versions of PyTest